# My Slide Out Menu was working in HTML but is not working in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I have a simple slide in and out menu, Hamburger to open and X to close. It was working great before I loaded it into PHP and onto Wordpress. When I copied to Wordpress I originally put the script in my head before my meta tags like I usually do, this didn't work. I tried it in a few other places too without success. When I am inserting this into PHP and previewing my site both the open and close button show up and when clicked the menu does not appear. I am new to this, so any help is appreciated. Thank you.

I attempted to make a working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/zq7egqzf/

```js
var button = document.getElementById("button");
    var d3 = document.getElementById("d3");
    function openNav() {
    button.style.display="none";
    d3.style.display="block";
    }

    function closeNav() {
    button.style.display="inline-block";
    d3.style.display="none";
    }
```

```css
 html {
    font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    }

    /* Header */


    header {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E1E0E1;
    margin-left: 35px;
    margin-right: 35px;
    height: 53px;
    }

    .sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    font-size: 36px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    opacity: 0.8;
    transition: 0.5s;

    }

    .sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #000000;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
    }

    .sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus {
    color: #BCBCBC;
    } 

    #d3 {
    display: none;
    }

    .lch {
    padding-top: 11px;
    padding-left: 13px;
    width: 85%;
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 1175px;
    position:relative;
    }

    .lolo {
    position: relative;
    width: 14%;
    min-width: 80px;
    max-width:
    }

    .wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: content;
    vertical-align: middle;
    }

    h1 {
    margin: 0;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-device-width: 540px) {
    h1 {width: 100%;}
    }

    @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
    .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
    }

    #button {
    padding-top: 15px;
    }

    .homephoto {
    margin:30px;
    }
```

```html
    <header>

    <div class="wrapper">

    <h1 class="menu">

    <input id="button" type="image" src="hamburger2.png" onclick="openNav()">

    <div id="d3">
    <input id="button" type="image" src="close.png" onclick="closeNav()">
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="sidenav">
    <a href="#"> &nbsp; &nbsp; - p o r t f o l 
    i o</a> <br>
    <a href="#"> &nbsp; &nbsp; - m e e t 
    &nbsp; l o l o</a><br>
    <a href="#"> &nbsp; &nbsp; - i n 
    s t a </a><br>
    <a href="#">  &nbsp; &nbsp; - p r e s s </a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">  &nbsp; &nbsp; - c i a o</a>
    </div>
    </div>

    </h1>

    <h1 class="lch"> <a href="#"> <img 
    src="lcg2.svg"/> </h1>
    <h1 class="lolo"> <a href="#"> ‎<img 
    src="lolo2.svg"/> </h1>

    </div>
    </header>

    <center>
    <div>
    <img class="homephoto" src="eclecticmaison.jpg"/>
    </div>
    </center>
```

Comment: Can you sen `head` tag code

Answer (score 0):

try changing your script into this

```
(function(){

var button = document.getElementById("button");
var d3 = document.getElementById("d3");
function openNav() {
    button.style.display="none";
    d3.style.display="block";
}

function closeNav() {
    button.style.display="inline-block";
    d3.style.display="none";
}

});
```

Comment: Okay, I will try that. Should it be in the top of the header file?

Comment: did you include this part
`(function(){` ?? it's supposed to make sure that your script will run after the page is loaded. I think your script is not working because it is being executed while there are still no DOM elements. try putting it also in the footer of the page